# Greasemonkey timer and replace

Tags: javascript, facebook, timer, greasemonkey

The timer should check and replace a text every 1 sec on Facebook chat submit message box

```
function gopi()
{
    chatDiv=document.getElementsByClassName('fbNubFlyoutFooter')[0].getElementsByClassName('inputContainer')[0].getElementsByClassName('uiTextareaAutogrow input')[0];

    for(x in chatDiv)
    {
        //var str=chatDiv[x].innerHTML;
        //str.replace("message2replace", "replacedmessage");
        if(chatDiv[x].innerHTML=="message2replace")
        {
            chatDiv[x].innerHTML="replacedmessage";
        }
    }

    setTimeout(gopi,5000);
    }

setTimeout(gopi,2000);

void 0;
```

Edit: If this is not able, then how can I make a box that replaces the text and send it?

Comment: You want to submit this message too?  Just for giggles, who do you plan to spam once per second?

Comment: Well, I want to use it for replacing a message with an image something like when you press :a: it won't send that message to user but it will send something like [[159589887500743]] which is letter A

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
function gopi() {
    var chatDiv = document.getElementsByClassName('fbNubFlyoutFooter')[0].getElementsByClassName('inputContainer')[0].getElementsByClassName('uiTextareaAutogrow input')[0];

    for (var x = 0, len = chatDiv.length; x < len; x++) {
        if (chatDiv[x].innerHTML == "message2replace") {
            chatDiv[x].innerHTML = "replacedmessage";
        }
    }   
}

setInterval(gopi, 1000);
void 0;
```

If that doesn't work your selector for the chatbox is wrong.